# OpenXML Spreadsheet update value in SharedStringTable

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am using OpenXML Spreadsheet in order to generate .xlsx file with a given template and a variable dictionary. But I have a question when updating the value in SharedStringTable since the InnerText of the SharedStringItem is read only. 
My template excel file is a file with .xlsx. The variables I need to replace has prefix "$$$". For example, "$$$abc", then in the dictionary I may have <"abc", "Payson"> pair (if the dictionary does not contain the key "abc", just leave the "$$$abc" there. 
What I have done is something like this

```
        private void UpdateValue(WorkbookPart wbPart, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {

            var stringTablePart = wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (stringTablePart == null)
            {
                stringTablePart = wbPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
            }
            var stringTable = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
            if (stringTable == null)
            {
                stringTable = new SharedStringTable();
            }
            //iterate through all the items in the SharedStingTable
            // if there is any text starts with $$$, find out the name of the string
            // look for the string in the dictionary
            // replace it if found, or keep it if not.
            foreach (SharedStringItem item in stringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
            {
                if (item.InnerText.StartsWith("$$$"))
                {
                    string variableName = item.InnerText.Substring(3);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(variableName) && dictionary.containsKey(variableName))
                    {
                        // The problem is here since InnerText is read only.
                        item.InnerText = dictionary[variableName];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The document is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlcompositeelement.innertext(v=office.14).aspx

Even the document mentioned that innertext can be set, however, there is no set accessor. 
Does anyone know how to set the InnterText. Since I may have many cells with the same variable name "$$$abc", and I would like to replace all of them with "Payson".

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to replace the InnerXml, then save the SharedStringTable.  See [Set text value using SharedStringTable with xml sdk in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061551/set-text-value-using-sharedstringtable-with-xml-sdk-in-net).

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, I don't think that's the problem. I am not assign a new thing to the item. Just update its InnerText property. However, since this property has only get, I cannot set the value. I want to know if there is other ways to do it. To edit the SharedStringTable. Thanks again

Comment: Perhaps what you need to do is to remove and add individual elements in the SharedStringTable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc797480.aspx includes some code for removing items from the SharedStringTable.  http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/35/p/6234/160671.aspx includes some code for inserting them.

Comment: Getting there -- it appears that this question might have already been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061551/set-text-value-using-sharedstringtable-with-xml-sdk-in-net.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to edit the Text and it works.

```
               Text newText = new Text();
                newText.Text = dictionary[variableName];
                item.Text = newText;
                stringTable.Save();
```